# Selected and highlited input after entering input by external devices like barcode reader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a barcode reader to fill an input field.

when i read the barcode usind the device **product-id** will be automatically filled in the input field.
when i trigger the device twice the input field will be filled twice with same **product-id**.

So i need the input field  selected and **ready to replace** after each iput from the device.

Answer (score 0):

jquery's .select() will focus the input element and will auto select all of the text in the input, ready to type over/replace.

https://api.jquery.com/select/

## Demo

http://jsbin.com/vuqinepogi/edit?html,output